# Dynamically change parameters based on the value of another parameter?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a crystal 2008 report that allows users to group to two levels.
I have two parameters, using which users can select which attribute they want to group on. 
The two params are of type string and the list of values is static. Both levels have the same options to group on.

Is there someway to filter the list based on what they selected for param 1. So that they cannot group on the same thing twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. You can cascade dynamic parameters link Country, State but not how you want to.

How many options do they have to choose from? Do they normally choose anything other than a few different combinations from the maximum?

I think you're options are to either leave it as is (allowing them to pick the same thing for both groups). Or create a single parameters which looks like- Group by:

Date, Country
Type, Country
Date, Type
etc

Comment: So I assume the Country,State works by making them dynamic.
Found this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FHYoYg9E4Q
I guess you are right, its not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: not possible.

Options:

- create a custom UI that does what you want to do
- if the list of grouping fields aren't too long, you could combine the two parameters into a single one, then list the options that you want to support.  For example, if you have 3 grouping fields (A,B,C), your single, combined parameter would be A->B, B->A, B->C, C->B, A->C, C->A.